# Is there a way to run a spreadsheet on 3 axis?

Tags: worksheet-function

Is there a way to run a 3D spreadsheet. I have a list of products in the columns and a list of options in the rows. But for each product and each option there is a price, a cost, a discount, a markup, a lead time, and a few other related information. Right now I have 7 tabs, all have the same column and rows. Each week an option is added, a product is added or removed, Each time I have to modify all tabs the same way and without misplacing a row or column. I can use a macro to do that. But is there a way in excel to really run 3 axis so that tabs are not independent, but all tied to the master and follow and formulas also take on 3 coordinates rather than 2?

Comment: Sounds like you're really on the edge of database territory, not spreadsheet.

Comment: You should create a single table with one column for product, one column for option, one column for each measure (price, cost, discount, markup) and optionally one column that represents the reason you had these separated in different tabs in the first place (perhaps the sheet name). Each cell in a table previously becomes one row in the new table. Once you have the data formatted like that, analysis and reformatting (via PivotTable) becomes a trivial exercise. If you add example data and more details to your post, I can add an answer showing you how to do this.

Comment: i think excel is not the best ways for your requirements... its just a feeling but access would perform better?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I used Access until 2007 before but got forced out by IT claiming MS was ending support. I saw a great power in Excel to customize forms (something Access lacked at the time). On the other hand, managing data in Excel is a bit more challenging. Your suggestion of transposing each cell to a column might work.